# issue in using Angularjs ui tree inside ng Dialog

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui, angular-ui-tree

I am trying to show angular js ui tree  inside ng dialog. Even though the appearance is fine but the check box functionality is not working. Similarly Select All, Collapse All, etc buttons functionality is also not working inside ng Dialog.  Can any one help me to fix this issue? Outside ng Dialog the tree functionality in relation to check boxes and buttons every thing is working fine, only in ng Dialog box it is causing the problem.  Please find my [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/dvo7vPV7E7hzbrpmvFC9?p=preview). I need to have UI tree in my html and in ngDialog too for different models as have shown in the plunker.

My  `parent_nodes_renderer_ngdialog.html` and `terminal_node_renderer_ngdialog.html` are slightly modified from my original `parent_nodes_renderer.html` and `terminal_node_renderer.html` to meet some of my requirements

Answer (score 0):

Few changes to be made in InsideCtrl to make it work and the functions should use treeData (i.e., ng Dialog related data structure, etc). Please find the fixed [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/G6VsNqOeRNAjFu0xlI5k?p=preview). Please make a note to the change to id of the element too.

```
var getRootNodesScope = function() {
      return angular.element(document.getElementById("tree-root-dialog")).scope();
    };
```